# Order by integer keep null in middle of positive and negative value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have value in a column of table like-

```
3,2,null,4,-1,-4,-2.
```

I want result like

```
4,3,2,null,-1,-2,-4.
```

Answer (score 3):

You want NULL treated as a zero:

```
order by coalesce(column, 0) desc
```